# copying a contents of a pointer to another

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
void my_strcpy(char *sour,char *dest){
 if(sour == NULL || dest == NULL){
  return;
 }
 dest = sour;
}
int main(){
 char *d = NULL;
 char *s = "Angus Declan R";
 //d = malloc(sizeof(strlen(s)+1));
 //my_strcpy(s,d);
 d = s;
 printf("\n %s \n",d);
 return 0;
}
```

In this i'm trying to make the pointer "d" to point to the location of what the "s" is pointing to. Why is that its not pointing to the location.

Comment: This question is a duplicate hundreds of times over, but is a bit confused by the other errors in there...

Comment: Are you looking for memcpy()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is a pass-by-value language.  [This question](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html) of the C FAQ can answer your question.  Note that even if you fix your function prototype, your algorithm isn't copying a string at all - just a pointer.  You can just replace that call with:

```
d = s;
```

In your `main` function.  The `malloc` is unnecessary, too - you're just leaking it.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `c` language is pass by value. Instead pass the address of the pointer.

```
void my_strcpy(char *sour,char **dest)
// Condition checking and then do -
    *dest = sour ;
```

Comment: @Angus Glad that I am helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

here *d and *s are two pointers you are just copying the address which is stored in the s pointer which is pointing to an array and array contains "Angus Declan R" , **d can't point to the address**

when u are declaring/defining like

int *s="Angus Declan R"; ---> initially an array is created in the code segment(which is read only area)and s is now pointing to the base address of that array.even u can't access string directly using *s.u have only option printing/accessing using address.

**the only reason is the array created in the code segment area of the memory.**

here %s prints value/string/char by using a base address until a null value encounters.
malloc is unnecessary,
in void my_strcpy()   dest = sour; is also unnecessary. it is just like d=s; .

pardon if explanation is not good.

Comment: I would really suggest using the code highlighting and block quoting in the site to help make your posts more readable. You'd elicit more responses to your question, and it would be more helpful to others who are having the same issue.